# Celery task succeeds when command it executes fails

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, task, celery

I have a tasks.py file that looks like this:

```
from celery import Celery
import subprocess
from flask import flash

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task(track_started=True)
def move_files(upRepo, filedir):
    subprocess.call(['aptly', 'repo', 'add', upRepo, filedir])

@app.task(track_started=True)
def make_snapshot(existRepoName, snapName):
    subprocess.call(['aptly', 'snapshot', 'create', snapName, 'from', 'repo', existRepoName])
```

The tasks go through fine, and when the `subprocess.call` command succeeds everything works, it's just when `subprocess.call` fails, the task still technically goes through, so Celery reports this as a 'Success'.

I've been looking at `after_return` in [the docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html), but I'm not sure if that's what I want, nor do I really know how I would implement that...

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `subprocess.check_call` -- it'll throw an exception if something goes wrong.

test case:

### source

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call('false')
```

### output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "zcheck.py", line 3, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call('false')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'false' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

For the original code, this becomes:

### tasks.py

```
from celery import Celery
import subprocess
from flask import flash

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task(track_started=True)
def move_files(upRepo, filedir):
    subprocess.check_call(['aptly', 'repo', 'add', upRepo, filedir])

@app.task(track_started=True)
def make_snapshot(existRepoName, snapName):
    subprocess.check_call(['aptly', 'snapshot', 'create', snapName, 'from', 'repo', existRepoName])
```

Comment: This, or [check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=check_output#subprocess.check_output), if you need to see the text response.

Comment: Thanks! doing an if statement to check the output of `subprocess.check_call` on the actual command with a failure initiating `subprocess.check_call('false')` works wonderfully. Thanks again!